# UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters position in 108308-108313

Tags: python

```
    fp.write(finalHTML)
  File "C:\Users\ME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 108308-108313: character maps to <undefined>
```

Code

```
19: today = datetime.date.today()
date_time_text = "<h3 style='text-align:center;'>" + today.strftime("Compiled on %d, %b %Y") + "</h3>"
```

```
42: finalHTML = "<body>" + book_title_text + date_time_text + "<br/><br/><br/>" + "</body>"
for readyEntry in finalEntriesInHTML:
    finalHTML = finalHTML + readyEntry.HTML + "<mbp:pagebreak/>"

fp = open(os.getcwd() + "/r2K-result.htm", "w")
fp.write(finalHTML)
fp.close()
```

idk why, but qhwn it is pulling from reddit, it has encoding error with charaacters :/

Comment: I wonder whether the problem will be solved if you add `encoding` parameter to the `open` function and set its value as `"utf-8"`. `open(os.getcwd() + "/r2K-result.htm", "w", encoding="utf-8")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wonder whether the problem will be solved if you add encoding parameter to the open function and set its value as "utf-8". open(os.getcwd() + "/r2K-result.htm", "w", encoding="utf-8"). – dildeolupbiten Apr 15 at 23:29